# pyathena returns columns name and value separately

Tags: python, pyathena

I have integrated pyAthena first time and after exection, I am getting columns name in description as tuples and values in other as tuples

```
 cursor = connect(s3_staging_dir = "s3 location").cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
```

**cursor.description** giving the columns name,

How can I get it as dictionary

Thanks